# How to enforce that only a single object, out of all objects, of a Model has a specified value for a field

Tags: django, database-design, django-models, django-orm

I am writing a model ModelX and it would have several obj1, obj2 etc for it

ModelX has a field fieldX

I want to ensure that for all obj1, obj2, obj3 etc, there is only one of them that has fieldX = "XXX", and none of the others have

I can put asserts in pre_save() or post_save(), but is there a cleaner way of doing this at database level, so that it raises an IntegrityError?

Thanks

#### update

I have a Link model, which has a foreignkey to User, an access_token = textfield, and bool is_active

I want to enforce that any time, for Link objects for a particular user, only zero or one object can have is_active True, and any number of objects can have is_active = False

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UNIQUE constraint works for both True and False values. If you really want to use it you have to make the `is_active` field nullable and use None (NULL) instead of False, as two NULLs are not considered equal (at least in PostgreSQL and MySQL).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use the 'unique' field option in the model definition https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#unique

Comment: obj1.FieldX = "XXX", obj2.FieldX = "YYY" , obj3.FieldX = "YYY" should be allowed in my case, but unique wont allow that

Comment: @dowjones123 perhaps you should explain a little more what it is you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I have updated my original post to give a better idea. Thank  you in advance